# How do I forbid a node within another?

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<a>
  <b>something</b>
  <c>something</c>
  <d>something</d>
</a>
```

And the following xslt, which is supposed to prefix namespaces to the nodes within `<a>`:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <a>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

But let's say I don't want to allow the xml to contain a node of type `<d>`. I'd like to terminate if this is the case. The following doesn't recognise work:

```
<xsl:template match="a/*">
  <xsl:if test="d">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">ERROR</xsl:message>
   </xsl:if>
  <xsl:element name="x:{name()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The above code just seems to do the same as if the `<xsl:if>` wasn't there at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` test isn’t testing what you think. Try this test to see if the matched element is of a particular name:

```
<xsl:if test="self::d"/>
```

Or this less elegant solution:

```
<xsl:if test="name() = 'd'"/>
```

Alternately, you could just add a template for `d` elements that behaves differently from other elements.

Comment: Neither has any effect.. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does anything happen if you change it to `test="true()"`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was using `xsltproc` and I didn't see the error message come up, it is working. THanks :)